# css that supports internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having a problem with my web page, Its viewing fine with any other browser other than internet explorer. I have tested with Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Safari, Torch and Internet Explorer Browsers. I know I am making a mistake with my CSS, can someone help me, here is the html and css files.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        <title>|| My Page Tittle ||</title>
        <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'  />
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='header'>
                My Header here
            </div>
            <div id='menu'>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'>My MENU1</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>my MENU2</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>my MENU3</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>my MENU4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>                  
            <div id='content'>                          
                <div id='left'>                 
                    <h3>My Header</h3>
                    <p>My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph
                    My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph
                    My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph My paragraph</p>
                </div>
                <div id='right'>
                    <p>Some Stuff will come Here Some Stuff will come Here Some Stuff will come Here</p>
                </div>                              
            </div>                  
            <div id='footer'>
                <p>And Finally the footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #C89D38;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;    
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#header {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100px;  
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: auto;
}

#menu {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #303030;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#menu ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;

}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu a{
    padding: 4px 30px 10px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 30px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background-color: #C89D38;
    color: #303030;
}

#content {
    width: 820px;
    min-height: 350px;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 40px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 15px solid #C89D38;
}

#left{
    float: left;
    width: 590px;
    min-height: 350px;
    background-color: #EBE8F4;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#right{
    float: right;
    width: 175px;
    min-height: 350px;
    background-color: #EBE8F4;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#footer{
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 15px solid #C89D38;
    clear: both;
}

#footer p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align:center;  
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? Or take a screenshot, or put it into a jsfiddle?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than "i am having a problem". *what problem are you having?*

Comment: @RobQuincey better "post screenshot AND put it into a jsfiddle"

Comment: You have no Doctype, that means you are in [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which is hellish. Beyond that, you haven't asked a real question. As several previous commentators have mentioned, you need to be more specific. You should also create a [sscce](http://sscce.org/), I don't expect that *all* that CSS is relevant to the problem.

Comment: make sure your syntax is correct some browsers doesn't care internet explorer does.

Comment: sorry guys for asking an incomplete question, @Quentin you answered my question, i had to include Doctype. The problem was that everything was left aligned in internet explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a preview of your site via JSBin http://jsbin.com/udovup/1

Now this looks fine in all but IE, because you are missing a `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the top of your HTML. This will be throwing IE into Quirks mode.

So add this to the top of your HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        <title>|| My Page Tittle ||</title>
        <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'  />
    </head> 
.
.
.
</html>
```

Comment: Damnit, Ninja'd me to it. He's right, looks exactly the same in IE8 and 7 when its in Standards mode and not the devil like Quirks mode.